# No option to share internet connection with computers using wifi

Tags: macos, wifi, internet-sharing

I'm trying to setup a hotspot from my macbook. From Settings -> Sharing, when I try select Internet Sharing from my WiFi connection, there is no option to share with other computers using WiFi.
I'm running macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Wi-Fi is the internet connection path, it cannot simultaneously share internet from the same interface.

This is similar to iOS's feature, where turning on Wi-Fi disables hotspot.

Comment: You're right. When I connect my iPhone via USB and share, I do have a WiFi option. Thanks!